# Maven project runs fine but many projects underlined red in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, maven-3, dependency-management

I was moved into a new team who all are junior like myself. I've set up the code on my machine. Maven clean / install *seems* to run fine along with running the run-configuration in Intellij

Having said that, i can see in the maven pane that all the projects are highlighted red either for unresolved plugins and/or dependencies

How does this work if the application seemingly builds fine and seemingly runs fine?

Could it be that the application is just not used in a way that shows the break?

Or maybe some dependency of a dependency requires something but still seems to work (or maybe not) anyway?

If the application still works but there are many modules underlined red for unresolved dependencies/plugins, what would you do? Should it he fixed? Ignored as  superfluous issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time when IntelliJ shows maven errors ('red unterlines' in maven tool), there are real problems or a complete remove of the maven project, clear of the .repository cache and IJ restart and select your problem project, right mouse click 'reimport project' eventually resolves it.

However every IJ version I've worked with in the past few years seems to have the same bug that after a successful reimport all problems are solved but the red underlines are not cleared, reimport, resync, nothing helps except a IJ restart. After a restart all red underlines are gone.

Comment: I regularly use the IJ 'invalidate caches / Restart' option whenever i see potential issues however it didnt't work here. Same with clearing maven repo

I've reimported the modules in this project multiple times as part of trying to get set up to work and it never resolved the red lines.

On a different machine (which had maven_repo with many jars from various old projects) i noticed it works fine without any red lines, which is what made me wonder whether there are missing unused dependencies. As a result ive backed up this maven repo folder as a precautionary.

Comment: When resetting up on the desktop from scratch (with new maven repo) i see the red lines on the second machine too

Comment: Not one hundred percent certain, but i tried reimporting all modules again, but this time select an option to download all sources/dependencies before confirming. Took a long while and a restart and i dont see the red lines anymore